# Any free skinable alternatives for Flowplayer for video playback?

Tags: internet-explorer, video, flash, free, open-source

Are there any good free skinable Flash video players, other than Flowplayer? I need something that works well in IE. Something open source would also be nice.

Comment: Has S.gfx answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at JW Player :

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player

http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/